# Cannot see projects in console after migrating from "no organization" to a new organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was originally creating all my GCP projects under a `my-name@gmail.com` account and they were automatically associated with an organization named `no organization`.

I then tried to start a new organization using Cloud Identity. For example, the new organization is named `my-org.com` and the new user associated with it is `my-name@my-org.com`.

And I tried to migrate the billing account and all the existing projects over.

Using `gcloud` CLI I can login with the new `my-name@my-org.com` user and run `gcloud projects list` to see all the projects correctly migrated. But if I open up the GCP console and login with the new user I cannot see all of the migrated projects in the "project switcher" popup. Only one or two of them are showing.

Clearing the cache and logging in and out does not help.

What could be happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Is your org correctly selected in the project switcher pane? You can switch from no org to org in the upper left corner

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere When logged in with `my-name@gmail.com` user I can see `no organisation` at the root and and one project listed underneath. Also there is no org switcher. If I login with the new `my-name@my-org.com` user I can see `my-org.com` is selected in the org switcher, but only one project shows out of all the projects that were migrated over to it. Switching to `No organisation` (while still logged in as `my-name@my-org.com`) shows no projects at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is working now, although I can't be sure what fixed it, I think going here while logged into `my-name@gmail.com` helped: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

On that page I could see all my projects listed under `no organisation` and so I selected them all and then clicked "move" to move them into the new org.

That seems to have triggered the correct update somewhere and now it's working.